# TexStudio using MikTex ignores \textit, \textbf and so on

Tags: fonts, luatex

I don't get any errors compiling my Tex file. I tried with the Editor from MikTex and there it works. Used an old Tex file, which also correctly displayed \textit, but I couldn't find the difference. The not working Tex file is quite big, I will upload the settings and the package section. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
As some users pointed out this post is not readable. While trying to change it to a question you can actually understand I noticed, that the problem only occurs if my code is imported into my main using \input. Copying the exact same lines into an empty document will resolve the issue. Which is of course kinda a solution but I really wonder why \input causes this issues.

packages:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
\usepackage{overcite}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}           %Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %Bilder einbinden
\usepackage{xcolor}                     %Farben für Schrift und Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %Plots und Tabellen aus Datensätzen.
\usepackage{amsmath}                        %Mathe
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %Mathesymbole
\usepackage{longtable}                  %Seitenübergreifende Tabellen zulassen
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}                   %Seitenränder
%optischer Randausgleich
\usepackage{setspace}                   %Zeilenabstand: \onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %Zeichenkodierung für Umlaute
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                   %für Dokumentformatierung mit Pagestyle
\usepackage{mhchem}                     %Chemische Formeln (mit \ce )
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{caption}                                        %Überschriften formatieren
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,it},tablename=Tab.,figurename=Fig.}             %Überschriften formatieren
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=raggedright}                


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}} %Abbildungs und Tabellennummerierung anpassen
\renewcommand*\figureformat {\figurename~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\thefigure.}  %Punkt nach Abb. #
\renewcommand*\tableformat {\tablename~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\thetable:}     %Doppelpunkt nach Tab. #

\renewcommand*\captionformat {~}                                %Nur Abstand, kein Zeichen nach Tab. #: bzw Abb. #. 

\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}}
   
%Literatur als Subsubsection definieren und von Literaturverzeichnis in Literatur umbenennen
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{\section{\bibname}           
\@mkboth{\subsubsectionmarkformat \bibname}{\subsubsectionmarkformat \bibname}}
\makeatother
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand*\bibname{Literature}} 


\usepackage{prettyref}                      %Nummerierung der Tabellen und Abbildungen im Text an Tab. x.x.# anpassen
%%% Für Abbildungen %%%
\newrefformat{fig}{Fig.~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\ref{#1}}
%%% Für Tabellen %%%
\newrefformat{tab}{Tab.~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\ref{#1}}


%Links im Dokument:
\usepackage[                                    %als letztes Paktet einbinden!
linkcolor=black,                            %Farbe der Links
citecolor=black,                            %Farbe der Link-Ziele
urlcolor=black,                             %Farbe von URLs
colorlinks=true,                            %Links nicht als Kasten, sondern direkt als Text anzeigen
]{hyperref}                                     %Links im PDF-File, unterstützung von URLs mit /url{}
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}
%Dokumentformatierungen
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

settings:

```
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\Roman{section}.}{1.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}{1.0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}{0.75em}{}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}     %Serifenschrift in Überschriften
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\pagenumbering{roman}                   %arabische Seitenzahlen

\geometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}   %Seitenränder
\parindent 0pt                                  %Absätze einrücken um 0Pt
\parskip 10pt                                   %Abstand nach Absatz
\onehalfspacing                             %Zeilenabstand
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                 %Kopf- und Fussleistenformatierung
\headsep0.4cm                               %Abstand Kopfleiste-Text
\footskip0.8cm                                  %Abstand Fussleiste-Text
\urlstyle{same}                             %URLs normal formatieren, nicht als Typewriter
```

the main im using:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                                        %Format
12pt,                                           %Schriftgröße
twoside,                                        %Zweiseitig
headsepline,                                %horizontale Linie oben
footsepline,                                    %horizontale Linie unten
captions=tableheading,                  %Überschrift über Tabelle (nicht unter)
]{scrartcl}
\brokenpenalty=1000000

\input{packages.tex}
\input{settings.tex}


\begin{document}

\input{title_content.tex}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.}{1.5em}{}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\sectionnumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}
\input{introduction.tex}


\section{Computational Methods}
\input{cpmethods.tex}

\section{Results and Discussion}
\input{results.tex}

\input{literature.tex}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\Alph{section}.}{1.5em}{}
\sectionnumbering{Alph}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\input{appendix.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have posted a _lot_ of code but no one can run it as it uses files we do not have, please make a small self contained document with no `\input`  that shows the problem and remove every package that you can remove while still showing the problem to help people trace the issue. In particular your example does not include any `\textbf` so is not a example of your problem with `\textbf` not working.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
I tried working my way backwards by copying the main, package and settings into the same document class and it suddenly worked. So the same code when using \input fails to show \textit and \textbf correctly but when the same lines are copied into the same document it doesnt. I am not sure how to present that.

Comment: Using your preamble and setting code and a simple document body with `text \textit{Italic} \textbf{Bold}` works well. Try it yourself! If the problem is always there then comment out step by step lines in the preamble until the problem goes away.

Comment: do you have the problem in every input file or only in one specific?

Comment: Every input file and also the "main" in which they get imported. Some of this input files are also completely empty, since  I will only add text to them later

Comment: oh should copied the content from settings.tex and packages.tex? Are you should that you copied from the right files, the one your document actually uses?

Comment: using `\input` or not will not affect the font use, you must have made a mistake while modifying the file and removed the code that is causing the issue. Start by removing all text apart from `\begin{document} \textit{abc}\end{document}` check that italic does not work, then make the smallest preamble you can that still has that issue.  Note also that if italic is not working the log file will have a warning (just showing the warning may be enough for peope to debug the issue)